# Quantum field theory with $\ln(\phi)$ potential

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral

Consider a quantum field theory with the following action

$$S[\phi] = \int d^dx \left(-\frac{1}{2}\phi\Box\phi -\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2 +m^d\ln\frac{\phi}{m^{(d-2)/2}}\right)\\=m^d \int d^dx \left(-\frac{1}{2}\tilde{\phi}\bar{\Box}\tilde{\phi} -\frac{1}{2}\tilde{\phi}^2 +\ln\tilde{\phi}\right)$$

where $\tilde{\phi} =\phi/m^{d/2-1}\quad \bar{\Box} = \Box/m^2$ and its path integral as follows

$$Z = \int [D\tilde{\phi}] \exp(-iS[\tilde{\phi}]) = \int [D\tilde{\phi}] \prod_{x_i \in \mathbb{M}^{1, d-1}}\tilde{\phi}(x_i)\exp(-iS_{free}[\tilde{\phi}])$$
Now, if we expand the measure as

$$[D\tilde{\phi}] = \prod_{x_i \in \mathbb{M}^{1, d-1}} d\tilde{\phi}(x_i)$$, then the path integral is simply an infinite product of gaussian integral of the form $$\int dx~ x~ e^{-x^T\cdot M\cdot x} = \int dx~  e^{-x^T\cdot M\cdot x+\ln x}$$ which we know should be zero. Can we then say that the path integral $Z = 0$ by extension?

Edit: Conversely, the QFT path integral can also be obtained by simply taking infinite versions of the Gaussian integral above.

Edit 2: One can also consider a special case of $\ln|\phi|$, because of which $Z = \operatorname{\det}^{-1}(\Box +m^2)$ because the corresponding gaussian integral would be $$\int dx~ |x|~ e^{-x^T\cdot M\cdot x} = \int dx~  e^{-x^T\cdot M\cdot x+\ln |x|} = \frac{1}{\operatorname{det}(M)}$$

Comment: What is $\ln$ of a negative argument? Consider to include an absolute value.

Comment: @Qmechanic I think you should take it in the spirit of the gaussian integral I wrote finally. No? Is the absolute value necessary?

Comment: @Dr.user44690 in your Gaussian integral the domain of integration is the entire real axis; which doesn’t make sense for the logarithmic potential. Also this theory’s Hamiltonian isn’t bounded from below, which means the QFT can’t be consistent.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov That is why I have added a version that has $\ln|\phi|$ as the potential. That would fix that right?